# Checkbox groups in @angular/forms:^0.2.0

Tags: forms, angular

I need two different groups of checkboxes. I've written the TS below which seems to work. But I can't seem to understand how the HTML for the form would look like to properly bind it to the form. Any suggestions?

```ts
  buildForm():void {
    let countryGroup = {};
    let shipperGroup = {};

    this.countryList.forEach(country => {
      countryGroup[country.key] = new FormControl(false);
    });

    this.shipperList.forEach(shipper => {
      shipperGroup[shipper.key] = new FormControl(false);
    });

    this.form = new FormGroup({
      countries: new FormGroup(countryGroup),
      shippers: new FormGroup(shipperGroup),
    });
  }
```

**Edit:**
Ok. So I don't even think this is the correct approach. I can't seem to find any example using checkboxes and/or multiselect.

What I need is basically a way to map the below. I need an array of the checked values (just as a normal POST would generate).

```
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foobar[]" value="foo">
    Foo
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foobar[]" value="bar">
    Bar
  </label>
```